# Echo in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Trying to find simple way of printing information in `makefile`. At the bottom is shown my simple `makefile`.

Line     `$(info aaa)` prints `aaa` fine.
But line  `echo 'aaa'` creates error `*** missing separator`

Is it possible to print info using echo in `makefile`?

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
DEPS = f1.h,hellomake.h

echo 'aaa'
$(info aaa)

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o f1.o 
        gcc -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o f1.o -I.
```

Comment: afaik - `echo` must be within a rule.

Comment: agree with Matthias down there, your `makefile` doesn't interpreted line by line. `rule` is what defines the flow of `makefile`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Makefiles are not executed line by line, but regarding the rule dependencies. Your echo statement does not belong to a rule, but `make` thinks it should, thus the error message.

If you want to generate a general output independent of any dependency, `$(info ...)` (or `$(warning ...)`) is the way to go.

Comment: Also, quotes/double quotes are unnecessary with this suggestion.
See https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/managing-projects-with/0596006101/ch12.html for a more detailed overview of the kind of `make` debugging expressions you can use.

Comment: I'd rephrase the second option `$(info ...)` etc. can be used top-level, but also within receipts, in the latter case the output really depends.

Answer (score 12):

You can use trick like this in your `Makefile`:

```
a = $(shell echo abc)
$(info $(a))
```

Why it can be useful instead of directly using string literal with `$(info)`? To print shell variables or output of certain commands in the message, e.g.:

```
msg = $(shell echo "PATH in shell: $${PATH}, timestamp: `date`")
$(info "PATH in Makefile: $(PATH), $(msg)")
```

Comment: Why not just `$(info abc)`?

Comment: For example, if you want to add shell variables to the message or use output of some command (e.g., `time`) as part of the string to be printed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be good to include an example for that use case in your answer? I mean, it's old, but if you think it's still a valid approach, why not explain it. In my opinion, *trick* explains nothing.

Comment: The question was asked by another person, but I can suggest the reasoning behind necessity of using `echo`; edited my answer to provide an example.

Comment: Either way, I think it's much better now. I really don't like to talk about “tricks” instead of solid technologies.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a `sayhello` target:

```
.PHONY: sayhello
sayhello:
        echo 'aaa'
```

Now you can run `make sayhello` to execute the `echo 'aaa'` command.

> A phony target is one that is not really the name of a file; rather it is just a name for a recipe to be executed when you make an explicit request.
>
> https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html

The `sayhello` target can also serve as a *subroutine* of the `hellomake` target:

```
hellomake: hellomake.o hellofunc.o f1.o sayhello
        gcc -o hellomake hellomake.o hellofunc.o f1.o -I.
```